# Not sure how string split actually works in this case

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I don't get the following:

In the following `String`:

`String s = "1234;x;;y;";`

if I do:
`String[] s2 = s.split(";");`

I get `s2.length` to be 4 and

```
s2[0] = "1234";  
s2[1] = "x";  
s2[2] = "";  
s2[3] = "y";
```

But in the string: `String s = "1234;x;y;;";`

I get:

`s2.length` to be 3 and

```
s2[0] = "1234";  
s2[1] = "x";  
s2[2] = "y";
```

?

What is the difference and I don't get 4 in the latter case as well?

**UPDATE:**
Using `-1` is not was I was expecting as behavior.
I mean the last semicolon is the end of the `String` so in the latter example I was also expecting `4` as length of the array

Comment: Your question is exactly what is mentioned in the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Thus I do not think it is a proper question

Comment: @AdelBoutros: I think you are being harsh here, sure the behavior is documented in the javadocs, but considering the amount of poor questions that get asked in SO, I believe Jim has asked a pretty decent question, with a rather odd quirk of a method. His only miss is to not check the javadocs before asking here.

Comment: Java’s `split` is mimicking Perl’s, which is why it works this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29),

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

**UPDATE:**

You have five substrings separated by `;` In the second case, these are `1234`, `x`, `y`,  and . As per the docs, all empty substrings (at the end) which result from the split operation would be eliminated.
For details, look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings
>   will be discarded.

The string `boo:and:foo`, for example, yields the following results with these parameters:

```
Regex   Limit   Result
  :       2     { "boo", "and:foo" }
  :       5     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
  :      -2     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
  o       5     { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
  o      -2     { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
  o       0     { "b", "", ":and:f" }   // all the empty substrings at the end were eliminated
```

Answer (score 4):

Trailing empty strings are omitted. However, there are ways to include them explicitly, if needed.

Comment: Yes, right, you want to ommit the last trailing empty string. I don't think you can do that ad-hoc, but you can always split just the prefix of the string if you are always sure the last element is semicolon: `s.substring(0, s.length() - 1).split(";", -1);`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21295331)

Comment: @Neo obviously they do, as currently my link points to some betting site... Regretfully, it is an answer of long while ago, from a less experienced me, and it will not be straightforward to reconstruct what was in there in the link. Thus, I will just remove it.

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Comment: I see.But I can't then get the exact same result as the first string, right?I.e. length 4 since the last semicolon is actually the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

Good question. If you check the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for `String.split()` and check the example with "boo:foo" then you can see that the trailing empty strings are omitted.

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
>
> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:
>
> Regex Result
>
> : { "boo", "and", "foo" }
>
> o { "b", "", ":and:f" }

Answer (score 1):

Thats default behavior of split method in java to not return empty tokens . ]

s.split("\;", -1); should return empty token

Answer (score 0):

Why not check what does the documention says first. Here is the link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

And here is your answer:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.